# Apply-family on two lists (to avoid nested for-loops)

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following:

```
myseq <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)
scores <- sample(seq(0, 1, by = 0.01), 10)
var1 <- sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = T)
var2 <- sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = T)
mydf <- data.frame(scores = scores, var1 = var1, var2 = var2)

myseq
[1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0

mydf
  scores var1 var2
1   0.10    1    0
2   0.06    1    0
3   0.74    0    0
4   0.15    1    0
5   0.40    1    1
6   0.96    0    0
7   0.04    1    0
8   0.71    0    1
9   0.94    1    1
10  0.38    0    0
```

For each value in `myseq`, I want to sum `var1` and `var2` for the subset of records where `scores` is greater than the value in `myseq`.

**I want to do this only using the apply-family functions (apply, lapply, tapply, sapply, mapply, etc.).** In other words, no nested for-loops.

So, for example:

The first value in `myseq` is `0.0`. All `scores` are greater than `0.0`, so I want to return `var1` = `6` and `var2` = `3`.

The second value in `myseq` is `0.1`. Only 7 of the 10 `scores` are greater than `0.1`, so I want to return `var1` = `3` and `var2` = `3`.

...so on and so forth...

In the end, I'd like to the final output to be a 11(r) x 2(c) matrix (or data frame or list) containing the sums for each var.

```
var1 var2
   6    3
   3    3
   ...
   ...
```

Note: 11(r) is because the length of `myseq` is 11; 2(c) is because there are two vars, `var1` and `var2`

Comment: slight note. Please use `set.seed` when generating data frames via functions such as `rnorm` or `sample` so we can double check our results with your expected output.

Comment: Great point; that's my bad. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
res<-t(sapply(myseq,function(x){apply(mydf[scores>x,2:3],2,sum)}))
```

Comment: This is awesome! What if I didn't know up front how many vars there are (in my example, there is var1 and var2, but suppose I wanted to generalize it for any number of variables? Could I do something like: sapply(myseq,function(x){apply(mydf[scores>x,-1],2,sum)})

Comment: Of course, I you have your scores var and an unknown number of vars, just replace mydf[scores>x,2:3] by mydf[scores>x,-1]. You can even leave all the columns with mydf[scores>x,] and remove the ones you don't want from the final table.

Answer (score 2):

One idea,

```
t(sapply(lapply(myseq, function(i) mydf[mydf$scores >= i,-1]), function(j) colSums(j)))
 #       var1 var2
 #[1,]    6    7
 #[2,]    6    7
 #[3,]    6    7
 #[4,]    6    6
 #[5,]    3    4
```

Comment: Fantastic, and your use of the -1 in the subset for mydf allows me to generalize beyond just two variables! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

tidyverse solution:

```
myseq <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)
scores <- sample(seq(0, 1, by = 0.01), 10)
var1 <- sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = T)
var2 <- sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = T)
mydf <- data.frame(scores = scores, var1 = var1, var2 = var2)

myseq
##  [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0

mydf
##    scores var1 var2
## 1    0.85    0    0
## 2    0.06    1    0
## 3    0.23    1    1
## 4    0.98    1    1
## 5    0.32    0    1
## 6    0.58    0    0
## 7    0.45    0    0
## 8    0.90    1    1
## 9    0.22    1    1
## 10   0.15    0    0

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map_df(myseq, ~filter(mydf, scores>.) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum), -scores))
##    var1 var2
## 1     5    5
## 2     4    5
## 3     4    5
## 4     2    3
## 5     2    2
## 6     2    2
## 7     2    2
## 8     2    2
## 9     2    2
## 10    1    1
## 11    0    0
```

Comment: Nice! This looks really clean. I'm not familiar w/ `purrr` but I'll definitely take a look!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to avoid excessive computations:

Order the scores and find the index where every element of "myseq" is larger than "scores":

```
o = order(mydf$scores)

i = findInterval(myseq, mydf$scores[o])
z = rep_len(0L, sum(!i)) #zeroes to add, later on, because x[0] results in 0-length
```

Calculate consecutive sums only once:

```
csv1 = cumsum(mydf$var1[o]) 
csv2 = cumsum(mydf$var2[o])
```

Subset the summations appropriately (I used `set.seed(1821)` to generate the data):

```
csv1[length(csv1)] - c(z, csv1[i])
# [1] 8 7 6 6 6 5 3 3 2 1 0
csv2[length(csv2)] - c(z, csv2[i])
# [1] 6 5 5 5 5 3 2 2 1 1 0
```

Since you mention >2 variables, the last operations can be substituted by

```
sapply(mydf[-1], function(x) { cs = cumsum(x[o]); cs[length(cs)] - c(z, cs[i]) })
```

Comment: Really interesting approach! Thanks for sharing. Curious, if I had ~5MM records, do you think this would outperform the approaches above?

Comment: @user451151 : The big advantages here are (1) `findInterval` avoids the `length(myseq) * length(mydf$scores)` inequality comparisons and (as `?findInterval` mentions for sorted "x"; i.e. your "myseq") it basically depends only on `length(myseq)`. (2) Computing the cumulative sum and subsetting it to get the wanted result avoids summing elements more than once -- there's no need to re-sum elements that are greater than multiple elements of "myseq".

Comment: Really great! It'll be fun to compare this approach to the others. Thanks so much, really appreciate your help!

Comment: Is it possible that there is one issue with this approach? Try using `set.seed(12)` and `myseq <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)` with `var1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)` and `scores <- sample(seq(0, 1, 0.01), 10, replace = T)`

Comment: (continued from above) `sum(var1)` = `7`, but the vector I am returning with `csv1[length(csv1)] - c(z, csv1[i])` is `6 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 1 0`. If you look at `scores[o]` it should be `0.00 0.02 0.03 0.07 0.17 0.18 0.27 0.64 0.82 0.95`. As such, I'd expect the first number in my result to be 7, since this is a >= approach (per `?findInterval`).

Comment: @user451151 : try the "left.open = TRUE" argument. Indeed, for exact equality, you need to account for however you want to specify the interval. Generally, I believe, playing with `findInterval`'s arguments is more than enough to handle all cases wanted

Comment: I must have had an old version of R, because left.open wasn't even available :) I've updated it and tested it out. It looks like the issue is there has to be some sort of adjustment if the `myseq` and `scores`' overlap. But so far, simply using the left.open and right.closed arguments are insufficient. Still searching :)

Comment: @user451151 : Could you provide an example of inconvenient "myseq" and "scores"? You might, also, consider adding a simple `if/else` to test any exact equality of the first element (which, more probably, messes the behaviour).

Comment: Yeah, definitely -- here's an example of `scores`: `c(0.76, 0.00, 0.17, 0.79, 0.41, 0.05, 0.56, 0.34, 0.18, 0.30, 0.90, 1.00, 0.12, 1.00, 0.50, 0.73, 0.10, 0.23, 0.37, 0.45)`. Definitely on board w/ the if/else part -- still trying to figure out what it is :P  And `myseq` is just `seq(0, 1, 0.1)`

Comment: @user451151 : Using the specific "scores" in the above comment and adding "left.open = TRUE" seems fine, unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

Using data table you could try:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(5)
myseq <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)
scores <- sample(seq(0, 1, by = 0.01), 10)
var1 <- sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = T)
var2 <- sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = T)
mydf <- data.frame(scores = scores, var1 = var1, var2 = var2)

setDT(mydf)
result <- t(sapply(myseq, function(x){ mydf[scores > x, lapply(.SD[, -1, with = F], sum)]}))

> result
      var1      var2     
 [1,] 4         4        
 [2,] 4         4        
 [3,] 4         3        
 [4,] 3         3        
 [5,] 3         3        
 [6,] 3         3        
 [7,] 3         3        
 [8,] 3         2        
 [9,] 2         1        
[10,] 1         1        
[11,] Numeric,0 Numeric,0
```